# Do SQL server prioritize select and update statements?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Assume that SQL server received both select and update statements to the same table at the same time from different threads and connections

Do any of them get prioritized?

I know that select statements are delayed until update completed if table is already locked for update (update statements locks table by default i am incorrect?). If table lock continue for a long time due to update, select statement gets cancelled with too much waiting error

So what happens when both received at the same time?

Comment: However you try two statements will not start executing at the same time, one of the will be first (even if it is by nanoseconds)

Comment: Deadlock detection. The command with the least amount of resources to undo will become the deadlock victim. This is always going to be a select command.

Comment: `UPDATE` locks the **rows** it is updating - not the whole table! (unless of course you update more than 5000 rows at once - then it might escalate to a table-level lock)

Comment: @lrb does that mean SQL server starts to execute both query and when see deadlock it cancels select statement right?

Comment: @marc_s ty for more details

Comment: The commonly chosen victim will be the one which costs the least to roll back, not time to complete, considering the workload already completed. That will normally, but not always be a select statement. - This behavior can be altered with the SET DEADLOCK PRIORITY (LOW / NORMAL) option.

Answer (score 2):

A `SELECT` statement will place a **shared lock** (S) on any rows it's reading - depending on the isolation levels, that lock will be held for various amounts of time. In the default `READ COMMITTED` isolation level, the lock is held only while actually reading the row - once it's read, the lock is released right away.

The **shared** lock is compatible with other shared locks - so any number of `SELECT` statements can read the same rows simultaneously.

The `UPDATE` statement will place an **update** (U) lock on the row it wants to update, to read the existing values. Then, after that's done, before the actual updated values are written back, the lock is converted into an **exclusive** (X) lock for the time the data is written. Those locks are held *until the transaction they're executing in* is committed (or rolled back).

An update lock is not compatible with another update lock, nor with an exclusive lock. It is compatible with a shared lock however - so if the `UPDATE` statement is currently only *reading* the existing values, another transaction might read those same values using a `SELECT` statement with a shared lock.

An exlusive lock is incompatible with anything - you cannot even read the row anymore, while an `X` lock is on it.

So if you have two statements that come in and try to access the same row, then:

- if the `SELECT` comes first, it will place a `S` lock on the row, read it, and typically release that lock again
- at the same time, the `UPDATE` statement can place a `U` lock on the row and read the existing values; the "promotion" of the lock to `X` will not be possible until the `S` lock has been released - if that's not happening, the `UPDATE` statement will wait, and eventually time out, if the `S` lock is never released
- if the `UPDATE` lock comes first, it will place an `U` lock on the row to read the existing values
- at the same time, another transaction could be placing a `S` lock on the row to read it
- and again: the `UPDATE` statement can only progress to the `X` level to write back the new values once the `S` lock is gone - otherwise it will time out
- if the `UPDATE` lock comes first, it will place an `U` lock on the row to read the existing values, and already places the `X` lock on the row to actually do the update
- then at this time, no other transaction can even read that row - they will have to wait (or time out, if it takes too long for them to get serviced)

Read [SQL Server Transaction Locking and Row Versioning Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) for a more in-depth overview of the topic and more details